# How to show data sent with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, post

I'm new to PHP and AJAX. Any advice is welcome. 
My ultimate goal is to store a JavaScript array in MySQL database on button click but first I am testing if I can send the JS array to a PHP script. I need help figuring out how to display the array sent with AJAX.

My HTML in submit-array.html

```
<button  onclick="submit()">Submit Array</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

My JS in submit-array.html

```
function submit() {
    var nameString = JSON.stringify(nameArray);
        $.ajax({
            url: "submit.php",
            type: 'post',
            data: nameString,
            success: function() {   
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Submitted Successfully";
            },
            error: function () {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Error";
            }
        }); // end ajax call
}
```

submit.php

```
if(isset($_POST['nameString'])) {
        $nameArray = json_decode($_POST[nameString]);
        echo $nameArray;
    }
    else {
        echo "nameString not received";
    }
```

When I run my code and hit the submit button, I see "Submitted Successfully" on the HTML page, and "nameString not received" on the php page.

Why is $nameArray not displaying after nameString is sent to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give your `data` a name, so there's nothing for PHP to put into `$_POST`.

You should have:

```
 data: {nameString: JSON.stringify(nameArray)}
        ^^^^^^^^^^--- $_POST key
                    ^^^^etc... $_POST value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **google chrome Deleoper tools** (Ctrl-Shift-I) Network tab  or similar option with **firebug in firefox**.
In above mentioned tools you can see every to the server and correspond response. Check them and you'll find your AJAX data.